# SQL query to XML output goes something wrong. the format is like text file

Tags: sql, export, helper, export-to-xml

I have a very interesting problem with  XML output from  SQL query.

```
DECLARE @DateStr VARCHAR(30), @sql nvarchar (4000)
SET @DateStr = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), dateadd(HH,+2,getdate()),120),'.','-'),':','-'),' ','_');
SET @sql ='bcp "SELECT top 1  [Kod] ,[Ad] FROM [SMFT].[dbo].[AlanKonya]  FOR XML PATH(''Cubik'') ,ROOT(''CubicDetails'')" queryout "\\\cgtserver\Development\Cubik_FIFOREPORT_' + @DateStr + '.xml" -T -S CGTSAPP\CGTSSQL120 -w -r -t'
EXEC xp_cmdshell @sql
```

the Output file seems like this.[notepad++][image: 1]

When I look with WinSCP editor it seems like this
[WinSCP][image: 2]

The file format  looks like a text format

I just want to  see like this [notepad++ ok ][image: 3]

Why does my XML output look like a Text file when other XML files I open look formatted?

I'm having trouble transferring the file with WinScp because it appears as a text file

I'm using SQL 2012 Standard edition.  I tried it in SQL 2016 enterprise  but I took the same result

Could you help me, please?

Best regards

here is  my new quert  that is worked

```
DECLARE @FilePath VARCHAR(4000)DECLARE @SQLStr NVARCHAR(4000),
    @Cmd NVARCHAR(4000),
    @Ret INT,
    @DateStr VARCHAR(30), @sql nvarchar (4000)
SET @DateStr = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), dateadd(HH,+2,getdate()),120),'.','-'),':','-'),' ','_');
SELECT @SQLStr = 'SELECT N''<?xml version=''''1.0'''' encoding=''''UTF-8''''?>'' + (SELECT CAST((SELECT * FROM [SMFT].[dbo].Cubik_FIFOREPORT FOR XML  PATH(''Cubik'') ,ROOT(''CubicFifoReport''), ELEMENTS XSINIL) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)))'
SELECT @SQLStr AS SQLStr
SELECT @FilePath ='\\cgtserver\DEVELOPMENT\Cubik_FIFOREPORT_' + @DateStr + '.xml'
SELECT @Cmd = ' bcp " ' + @SQLStr + '" queryout '+@FilePath+'  -c -r  "" -T -S ' +@@ServerName
EXEC @Ret = master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @Cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

Your output file is in UTF-16 encoding with BOM. WinSCP internal editor does not support UTF-16, while Notepad++ does.

If you want to use WinSCP internal editor do view/edit the file, export the file using a different encoding. Use `bcp` `-C` switch for that. The best would be to use UTF-8 (`65001`), but it's supported since SQL server 2016 only. With 2012, you would  have to resort to "ANSI/Microsoft" encoding (`ACP`), but that's not binary safe. See [`bcp` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility).

```
queryout -C{65001} "path"
```

---

Are you aware that you can [configure WinSCP to edit files in Notepad++](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration_editor#notepad) instead of the internal editor?

Comment: Yes, I understand the situation. I wrote a new query. I used the cast function to convert XML output to varchar. It seems to work
But, I have another problem. 
When I exec this query the output file size is increasing  and adding white space at the end of the file
Could  you help me with this problem? 
 I added my new query at the end of the main question